Chemfig colouring of chemleft and chemright issue
I'm using chemfig to draw some figures that then I'd like to insert in other documents and ppts, hence using standalone to export .png with magick. That's not an issue, been doing it a lot.
I'm using miktex with texmaker compiling with pdflatex, all updated to most recent versions.
I have an issue when trying to colour figures, particularly within a schemestart/schemestop environment. Look at the following example:
\documentclass[multi=my,border=5]{standalone}
%,convert={density=300,outext=.png}

\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,140,58}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{22,80,197}
\definecolor{ansblue}{RGB}{68,114,196}
\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\begin{document}
\begin{my}
\Huge
\color{green}
\setchemfig{chemfig style={line width=2pt, color=green}, double bond sep={3pt}, arrow style={thick, line width=4, color=green}}
\schemestart
\chemleft{[}
\subscheme{
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=-)}
\arrow{<->}
\chemfig{*6(=-=-=-=)}
}
\chemright{]}
\schemestop
\end{my}

\begin{my}
\Huge
\color{green}
\setchemfig{chemfig style={line width=2pt, color=green}, double bond sep={3pt}, arrow style={thick, line width=4, color=green}}
\schemestart
\chemleft{[}
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=-)}
\chemright{]}
\schemestop
\end{my}

\begin{my}
\Huge
\color{green}
\setchemfig{chemfig style={line width=2pt, color=green}, double bond sep={3pt}, arrow style={thick, line width=4, color=green}}
\chemleft{[}
\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=-)}
\chemright{]}
\end{my}
\end{document}

And these are the outputs of the three standalone environments:



What am I doing wrong? Or how should I edit the colouring inside schemes?
Here below you can see the configurations (which I believe are the standard/default ones) from PDFLaTeX used.


Welcome to TeX.SE!

@Mensch thanks!

I compiled with pdflatex in TeXLive 2024 and it worked perfectly.
What compiler are you using?
Is your system up to date?


Oh. I'm using MikTex on TexMaker. There were updates available, but I've just updated everything on MikTex and problem persists. Maybe I should try downloading texlive to try? I've recently reinstalled miktex so it's the newest version, also.

open texmaker and check in the software settings which compiler you are using (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, etc.), choose pdflatex and try to compile your code.

yes, I'm using pdflatex. Same problem arises if I try lalatex, xelatex, or any other. I've just thrown the code in overleaf and it does compile perfectly, so I'm accepting this as an answer. Just out of curiosity, now I'm editing the question with configurations from texmaker (sorry I'm far from an expert here). Would you mind telling me if there is anything there that might be causing the problem?

The texmaker software is not responsible for the problem, it is just a "front-end" for the LATeX programs (or pdflatex, or xelatex, etc.)
The problem must be in MikTex, probably
